# MSVS Git - How to QA someone's work while ignoring my local commit/changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am doing both A) QA others' work and B) new feature dev myself.
The QA will be in a pull request in its own branch.
I want to look at, and possibly modify, the QA work ignoring my local commits/uncomitted changes.
Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Stash your work or use Git worktree.

Comment: What does QA mean? What does QA someone's work mean?

Comment: to test, QA=Quality Assurance